# How to spin up a TURN server in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, webrtc, video-streaming, amazon-linux, coturn

I need to spin up a TURN/STUN server in Cloud. I feel it a pretty common use case and there are hundreds of related posts in the internet. After several days of failed attempt, I still failed to spin it up.

Here is my current step. I keep it simple to be reproduced (only take ~10mins). I've no idea which part could go wrong.

### 1. Launch an (Amazon Linux 2.0 , t2.micro) host

- allow ALL traffic in SecurityGroup (only for quick test, remember to
  delete the rule)
- put it in public Subnet in default VPC grant it
- public IP address.

### 2. ssh into the host run following commands

```
sudo yum -y update
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel
sudo yum -y install coturn
```

### 3. start server

```
export PRIVATE_IP=172.31.28.133
export PUBLIC_IP=34.222.45.31
sudo turnserver -n --listening-port 3478 --listening-ip ${PRIVATE_IP} \
--relay-ip ${PRIVATE_IP} --external-ip ${PUBLIC_IP} \
--allow-loopback-peers --no-auth --no-tlsv1 --no-tlsv1_1 \
--log-file /tmp/turnserver.log --simple-log --fingerprint \
--min-port=49152 --max-port=65535 --verbose --no-cli
```

Now we will be able to see server up and running in 3478 port (default turn server port)

---

But this server is not running functional, there are a few problems with it:

1. ssh the host in new tab, run `curl localhost:3478`, it will respond: `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer` (Expect to see default "TURN Server" html page)
2. from random machine (not within the VPC), run `curl <EC2ExternalIpAddress>:3478`, it has no response, not even Recv failure message
3. trickle ICE shows "TURN server not reachable"

What could be problem with it?

Comment: You can use something like `ps aux | grep turn` to ensure coturn is actually running. Then something like `netstat -tunapl | grep turn` to verify what ports is coturn actually listening on. Then you can use https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/ to verify basic connectivity from your computer to the server. You should take network traces on your machine while you do that. I wrote time ago a troubleshooting guide that maybe can be useful: https://www.giacomovacca.com/2022/05/troubleshooting-turn.html